# ошибка при установленных исключениях

Tags: python

объясните почему при вводимых данных 20 0 10 , данный код выводит ошибку если установлены исключения ?

```
# ввод
r30, r10, r20 = (int(num) for num in input().split())
# все возможные числа для перемножения

numbers = []
r30_1 = r30
while r30_1 >= 0:
    numbers.append(r30_1)
    r30_1 -= 1

numbers.reverse()

numbers = numbers[:numbers.index(r30) + 1]

res_list1 = [r10 * x for x in numbers if isinstance(x, int)]
res_list2 = [r20 * y for y in numbers if isinstance(y, int)]

# оставить только числа до конечных
try:
    res_list1 = res_list1[:res_list1.index(r30) + 1]
    res_list2 = res_list2[:res_list2.index(r30) + 1]

    for a in res_list1:
        for b in res_list2:
            if (a + b) == r30:
                print(a // r10, b // r20)

except ZeroDivisionError:
    for a in res_list1:
        for b in res_list2:
            if (a + b) == r30:
                if a == 0:
                    print(a, b // r20)
                if b == 0:
                    print(a // r10, b)

except ValueError:
    for a in res_list1:
        for b in res_list2:
            if (a + b) == r30:
                print(a // r10, b // r20)
```

Comment: При каких входных данных? И если ошибка падает внутри блока обработки исключения, а у вас там запросто может упасть - код же у вас там зачем-то повторяется и деление на ноль вполне возможно, то там уже некому исключение ловить.

Comment: про входные данные я написал , а как решить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сначала случается exception `ValueError`, во время обработки которого уже в этом блоке происходит деление на ноль при вычислении выражения `a // r10`:

```
except ValueError:
    for a in res_list1:
        for b in res_list2:
            if (a + b) == r30:
                print(a // r10, b // r20)
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

При обработке exception не рекомендуется выполнять какой-то сложный код, который что-то вычисляет, рекомендуется просто напечатать какую-то информацию.

Но если очень хотите, можете туда тоже встроить блок обработки исключений и тогда ошибки не будет:

```
except ValueError:
    try:
        for a in res_list1:
            for b in res_list2:
                if (a + b) == r30:
                    print(a // r10, b // r20)
    except:
        print('We need to go deeper')
```

Вложенность блоков обработки исключений может быть любой, но обычно так всё же не делают, исключение - это исключительная ситуация, после которой обычно выполнение кода всё же прекращают.